# How to join these queries?

Tags: mysql

I have two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM `kamcms_forum_post` 
WHERE date=(SELECT max(date) 
FROM `kamcms_forum_post` 
WHERE `forum_topic_id` = [THERE IS PLACE FOR `forum_topic_id` from second query])

SELECT *, count(*) as posts 
FROM `kamcms_forum_topic` as t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `kamcms_forum_post` as p  ON t.forum_topic_id = p.forum_topic_id 
GROUP BY t.forum_topic_id ORDER BY p.forum_post_id
```

First query takes last post from topic, second query takes first post from topic and topic_name (from other table)  and count of all posts from topic. How can I join these queries?

Input:

`kamcms_forum_topic`
[image: http://screenshooter.net/102363018/ynselub]
`kamcms_forum_post`
[image: http://screenshooter.net/102363018/ihdjpdf]

Output:

title FROM forum_topic,
First post user_id and Last date and user_id from forum_post.

Comment: Output needs to be better explained! Not quite sure what exactly is your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem, your second query will always return at least 1 for count on a topic with your left join.  This should be pretty close from what I can understand of your request.

```
SELECT t.title, p.user_id, p2.user_id, p2.date, count(p.forum_topic_id) as posts 
FROM kamcms_forum_topic as t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN kamcms_forum_post as p ON t.forum_topic_id = p.forum_topic_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN kamcms_forum_post as p2 ON t.forum_topic_id = p2.forum_topic_id 
WHERE p.date=((SELECT MIN(date)
    FROM kamcms_forum_post sp where sp.forum_post_id = p.forum_post_id)
AND p2.date=((SELECT MAX(date)
    FROM kamcms_forum_post sp where sp.forum_post_id = p2.forum_post_id)
GROUP BY t.forum_topic_id ORDER BY p.forum_post_id
```

Comment: It doesn't work, becuase:
- always return first user_id for example for:
I edited user_id from 1 to 2 for forum_post_id = 2 and it still return:

Comment: *
It doesn't work, becuase:
- always return first user_id for example for:
I edited user_id from 1 to 2 for forum_post_id = 2 and it still return:
user_id = 1 and second user_id = 1 (last, when should return 2).
- return first, not last date for example for forum_topic_id = 1 it returns
2015-02-23 00:00:00 when should returns 2015-02-24 00:00:00

Comment: @BartoszŚledź added a little more.

Comment: It didn't work but i added one more ")" at end of lines:
FROM kamcms_forum_post sp where sp.forum_post_id = p.forum_post_id))
AND
FROM kamcms_forum_post sp where sp.forum_post_id = p2.forum_post_id)

Now It compiles but the same problem like before.
Still user_id is always the same (in both the same, from first) and return first date, not last date. :(

Answer (score 0):

Final query:

```
    SELECT t.title, p.user_id, p2.user_id, p2.date, count(p3.forum_post_id) as posts 
FROM kamcms_forum_topic as t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN kamcms_forum_post as p ON t.forum_topic_id = p.forum_topic_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN kamcms_forum_post as p2 ON t.forum_topic_id = p2.forum_topic_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN kamcms_forum_post as p3 ON t.forum_topic_id = p3.forum_topic_id 
WHERE p.date=(SELECT MIN(date)
    FROM kamcms_forum_post sp where sp.forum_topic_id = p.forum_topic_id)
AND p2.date=(SELECT MAX(date)
    FROM kamcms_forum_post sp where sp.forum_topic_id = p2.forum_topic_id)
GROUP BY t.forum_topic_id ORDER BY p.forum_post_id
```

Thanks for help